# Why do I lose reputation when I downvote?

Tags: bug, reputation, voting, down-votes

## Problem

I've recently reached 125 reputation on a Stack Exchange site, (yay!) and I now have the privilege to downvote. So I tried it out, and I lost a reputation point. At first I thought I got downvoted on a post, but then I remembered that when that happens, it's -2. So the I decided to ignore it, but then I found a bad answer to a question, so I decided to downvote it too. Then I lost another reputation point, and that's when I got nervous that there was something wrong. So I resorted to the help center, and it told me that when I downvote, I lose a reputation point. ***Why is this?***

Comment: I'm not sure "bug" is the right tag for this question, as you mentioned, this is something you found is written in the help center

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's how the system works!

> You lose reputation when:
>
> - your question is voted down: −2
> - your answer is voted down: −2
> - **you vote down an *answer*: −1** [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

The point is, to discourage users from downvoting unless they have a good reason to do so.

Comment: So I won't loose a reputation point if I downvote a question, but I will if I downvote an answer?

Comment: That's correct. You only get -1 for down-voting answers

Comment: Note, however, that if the answer is bad enough to be deleted, you will get your reputation point back.